# Verdacht "schöpfen", "nähren" und "hegen"

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen (Bedeutungs-)Unterschied zwischen den drei Verben "schöpfen", "nähren" und "hegen" in Bezug auf Verdacht?
Laut  [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Verdacht)  werden sie ziemlich mit der gleichen Häufigkeit verwendet, allerdings kann ich aus den Beispielsätzen keine Unterschiede erkennen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schöpfen bedeutet erstmaliges Erzeugen eines Verdachts:

„Als der Kommissar die Farbspuren an dem Auto sah, schöpfte er Verdacht.“

Nähren bedeutet Erhärten/Verfestigten eines Verdachts:

„Die Tatsache, dass sich auf dem Beifahrersitz eine Strumpfmaske befand, nährte seinen Verdacht.“

Hegen ist „neutral“ und bedeutet in diesem Kontext Haben:

„Der Kommissar hegte den Verdacht, der Karl könne das Verbrechen begangen haben.“